# Error when trying to import with CSV file format in Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

`HTTPError 400: Unknow export file type` was thrown when I try to Import csv file from my Cloud Storage bucket into my Cloud SQL db. Any idea what I missed out.

Reference:
[gcloud sql import csv](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/import/csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV files are not supported in Cloud SQL, MS SQL Server. As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/import-export#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20In%20Cloud%20SQL%2C%20the%20current%20SQL%20Server%20support%20for%20imports%20and%20exports%20consists%20of%20the%20following%3A),

> In Cloud SQL, SQL Server currently supports importing databases using
> SQL and BAK files.

Somehow, it is supported for MySQL and PostgreSQL versions of Cloud SQL.

You could perform one of the next solutions:

1. Change the database engine to either PostgreSQL or MySQL (where CSV files are supported).
2. If the data on your CSV file came from an on-premise SQL Server DB table, you can [create](https://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-backup-a-table-in-sql-server) an SQL file from it, then use it to import into Cloud SQL, SQL Server.